# Jekyll GitHub page on Raspberry

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages, raspberry-pi2

Recently I have set up the (Beautiful) Jekyll on GitHub.io and made it available on my own domain. But I was thinking if there is a way how to avoid GitHub.io and create own Git on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) and connect it with RStudio for changing the blog. I found [article](http://oopsmonk.github.io/blog/2015/03/05/build-a-blog-with-jekyll-on-raspberry-pi) that is cloning the GitHub.io repo and then pushing it live but making the changes to the blog is not very user friendly though. I have also found [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/GitPi-A-Private-Git-Server-on-Raspberry-Pi/) but not sure if it's possible to expose it online and then pull the jekyll page from my domain (like CNAME and dns config on domain in case of GitHub.io).

Final solution should work similar to this: change the Jekyll blog in RStudio (saved on laptop / cloned the current version from Rasp git) -> push the change to GitHub on Raspberry (and most recent version is exposed to domain as in case of GitHub.io). Any ideas or experience on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Github for hosting, you should use it for your repo too. I see no gain in using a Raspberry Pi as your own Git. So pull the git repo from Github to your laptop. Edit the markdown (in RStudio if you want) and push it back to Github. Simple.

**UPDATE:** If you do not want use Github you might as well forget about Git too. First, [install apache2 on your Raspberri Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md) to make it a web server. Then, connect the domainname. Configure the vhost to point to the domain name and configure the DNS settings to point to your Raspberri Pi (I guess this requires a fixed IP). Finally, run Jekyll on your laptop and build the site. After building you should upload the '_site' folder to the Raspberri Pi in the public_html directory. That should do the trick.

I would NOT recommend this last approach as it seems overly complicated.

Comment: I'm doing that currently, the point is that I want to avoid putting anything on GitHub. I understand it sounds silly though. So I should create just a repo in RaspPi, the question is how to make it accessible from the internet and make Jekyll live on own domain.